# Starting from j = i +1 vs j = 1 in a nested for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, variables

For the piece of code below, I am using a vector that contains the items {1, 2, 3} and I just want to get the sum of the product of the pairs, for example (1*2) + (1*3) + (2*3) which is 11.

```
for(unsigned i = {0}; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    for(unsigned j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); ++j) {
    //              ^^^^^^^            
        preresult = vec.at(i) * vec.at(j);
        result += preresult;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when I had in the inner loop `j` starting from 1, my answer was 30 and I got the right answer only when I changed to `j = i + 1`.

Can someone explain to me why? Would not `j = 1` work just fine?

Comment: If you started from 1, you'd include each pair twice and "pairs" of each number with itself.

Comment: `int ans = 0; for(int i=0;i<3;i++){ans += v[i]*v[(i+1)%3];}`

Comment: Use the debugger, step through the program, and you'll see what it's doing.

Comment: @AviBerger Please, consider expanding your comment (pointing out the difference between *all* the possible pairs and *distinct* pairs) into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only 3 values, so we can unroll the loops in a short space

Starting at `j = 1`

```
result += vec.at(0) * vec.at(1); // 2
result += vec.at(0) * vec.at(2); // 3
result += vec.at(1) * vec.at(1); // 4 Oops: pairing 2 with itself
result += vec.at(1) * vec.at(2); // 6
result += vec.at(2) * vec.at(1); // 6 Oops: Seen already
result += vec.at(2) * vec.at(2); // 9 Oops: pairing 3 with itself
```

Starting at `j = i + 1`

```
result += vec.at(0) * vec.at(1); // 2
result += vec.at(0) * vec.at(2); // 3
result += vec.at(1) * vec.at(2); // 6
```